# sum_all function is not useable inside of sum_all_invoice function

Tags: python

```py
def sum_all():
    total = 0

    # Iterating through the labels of each meal using a loop
    for i in range(1, 7):
        label_name = f"meal_{i}_line"

        # Accessing the values directly by reaching the labels
        label = getattr(self.ui, label_name, None)

        label_text = label.text()

        try:
            # Adding the number inside the label to the total variable
            total += int(label_text)
        except ValueError:
            # If the value inside the label is not a numerical expression, an error is displayed.
            # You can handle the error situation here.
            print(f"Error: No numerical expression found inside the {label_name} label. Defaulting to 0.")
            total += 0

    self.ui.price_line.setText(str(total))  # print to the price

    # VAT calculation
    def vat(total):
        vat_value = total * 0.18
        return vat_value

    vat_value_to_write = vat(total)
    self.ui.vat_line.setText(str(vat_value_to_write))  # print to the VAT line

    # Service charge calculation
    def service(total):
        service_charge = total * 0.1
        return service_charge

    service_charge_to_write = service(total)
    self.ui.service_charge_line.setText(str(service_charge_to_write))  # print to the service charge line

    # Calculate all
    def sum_all_invoice():
        meal_value = sum_all()  # causes an error when added
        vat_value = vat(total)
        service_value = service(total)

        total1 = vat_value + service_value + meal_value
        return total1

    sausage = sum_all_invoice()
    self.ui.subtotal_line.setText(str(sausage))

# Call the sum_all function when the button is clicked
self.ui.total_button.clicked.connect(sum_all)
```

I can print sum_all data in price_line but,
I can't use it inside of `sum_all_invoice()` function.

`sum_all_invoice()` function is collecting all of the functions to make this:

`total1 = vat_value + service_value + meal_value`

but it doesn't take the `meal_value`.

When I didn't add, meal_value to total1 like this:
`total1 = vat_value + service_value` it's working fine.

Error:

```
meal_value = sum_all()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Comment: "causes an error when added" -> *What* error? Also, `sum_all` doesn't return nothing. Please take your time, and [edit] your question with a valid [mre], as right now the indentation is completely off and we cannot understand where functions actually start or end, or even if you actually have nested functions.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  It's not common for an inner function to call the outer enclosing function except when doing recursion, which is clearly not the case here.

Are you getting an error message? Why do you think this isn't working?

Comment: You've created an infinite loop - sum_all calls sum_all_invoice which calls sum_all which calls sum_all_invoice ad infinitum

Comment: @FrankYellin I need to collect calculated result of these 3 functions. I can collect 2 functions but It gave error on 1 function which it's sum_all(). Is it not possible?

Comment: What you are doing makes no sense.  As someone notes above, you have `sum_all` calling `sum_all_invoice` which calls `sum_all` which calls `sum_all_invoice`.  Having an inner function calling its enclosing function is a sign of badly designed code.

Comment: @AllanElder :o what should I do? I wrote total += 0 in the except block because even if some of the meal_{i}_line values are empty, I want the code to continue running. When I wrote return 0 in except block and it couldnt find data in one of the meal_{i}_line, loop was breaking and was not collecting the other meal_{i}_lines who has the data

Comment: Did you mean to write: `meal_value = total`?

Comment: @FrankYellin yeah I'm not proud of this code or I'm not trying to prove something. I'm just trying to get help to make my code work because I couldnt do it by my own for 2 days :( sorry

Comment: @quamrana no I'm calling the sum_all() function there but it's not coming

Comment: I can see that you call `sum_all()`, but firstly that function never returns anything, and second, you get the recursion error. I'm sure you would get better results with `meal_value = total`

Answer (score 0):

```py
def sum_all():
    total = 0

    # Iterating through the labels of each meal using a loop
    for i in range(1, 7):
        label_name = f"meal_{i}_line"

        # Accessing the values directly by reaching the labels
        label = getattr(self.ui, label_name, None)

        label_text = label.text()

        try:
            # Adding the number inside the label to the total variable
            total += int(label_text)
        except ValueError:
            # If the value inside the label is not a numerical expression, an error is displayed.
            # You can handle the error situation here.
            print(f"Error: No numerical expression found inside the {label_name} label. Defaulting to 0.")
            total += 0

    self.ui.price_line.setText(str(total))  # print to the price

    vat_value_to_write = vat(total)
    self.ui.vat_line.setText(str(vat_value_to_write))  # print to the VAT line

    service_charge_to_write = service(total)
    self.ui.service_charge_line.setText(str(service_charge_to_write))  # print to the service charge line

    sausage = sum_all_invoice(total)
    self.ui.subtotal_line.setText(str(sausage))


# VAT calculation
def vat(total):
    vat_value = total * 0.18
    return vat_value

# Service charge calculation
def service(total):
    service_charge = total * 0.1
    return service_charge

# Calculate all
def sum_all_invoice(total):
    vat_value = vat(total)
    service_value = service(total)

    total1 = vat_value + service_value + total
    return total1

# Call the sum_all function when the button is clicked
self.ui.total_button.clicked.connect(sum_all)
```

This is just a slightly better arrangement of your code.

The separate functions are now standalone, which means they can be tested individually.